# Why does the simple arithmetic subtraction not work in the "if" condition?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, debugging, unordered-map

I have 2 arrays with elements in them. I used hashing to get the frequencies of each element which occurs more than one time. `mapcheckA` contains the frequencies of elements of first array and `mapcheckB` contains the frequencies of the other array. I am trying to delete/erase any duplicates of elements from both the unordered maps. Here is the code that does it:

```
for (auto i : mapcheckA) {
  if (mapcheckB.find(i.first) != mapcheckB.end()) {
    if (i.second >=
        mapcheckB.find(i.first)
            ->second) {  // This block of code doesn't work as expected
      i.second -= mapcheckB.find(i.first)->second;
      mapcheckB.erase(i.first);
    } else {
      mapcheckB.find(i.first)->second -= i.second;
      mapcheckA.erase(i.first);
    }
  }
}

for (auto i1 : mapcheckA) {
  cout << i1.first << "\t" << i1.second << endl;
}

for (auto i : mapcheckB) {
  cout << i.first << "\t" << i.second << endl;
}
```

When I enter elements in such a way that first array contains element with more frequency than in the second array, like this:

```
arrayA = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4 ];  // Here frequency of "1" is 4.
arrayB = [ 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3 ];  // Here frequency of "1" is 2.
```

In this situation the block of code in the "if" condition does not change the frequency of 1 to 2.
If I change the order of arrays, then the code works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: when I print the key-value pairs, for the above 2 arrays the output comes:
For arrayA:
`4  2`  `1  4`
For arrayB:
`3  2` `2  2`

Comment: In the loop `for (auto i : mapcheckA)` you are operating on copies of the elements, did you mean to operate on references to the actual objects (`for (auto& i : mapcheckA)`)?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius After inserting `&` before `i` in `for (auto i: mapcheckA)`, the problem is resolved. But I did not understand why and how did it resolve it.

Comment: @BennyK But it was working fine. When frequency of some element in second array was greater than in first, the output was correct. I was facing an issue when the frequency in first array was greater than the second one.

Comment: @Thomas Sablik - Sorry, missed the "unordered maps" part.

Comment: @PriyanshuRaj "_the problem is resolved. But I did not understand why and how did it resolve it._" But.. I explained it in my comment..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Many beginners don't understand that objects are copied in C++. Or what the implications of that are.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Now, i got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two significant bugs:

1. working on a copy of the data (already identified in comments).  Working with a reference means changes will be reflected in original container, rather than discarded when the copy goes out of scope.

   for (auto& i : mapcheckA) {  // add the &
2. undefined behavior
   In your "else" case, you remove the element that is current in the iteration, invalidating iterator i, but the loop continues to increment i.  Program state is indeterminate and this must not be done.

Unfortunately, with a ranged for loop, there is no good way to do this.  Your options:

- remember the key (or iterator) for later, and remove them after the loop
- hand roll the loop for manual iterator incremeting:

```
for (auto i = begin(mappedA), e = end(mappedA); i != e; ) {
    if (...) {
        ...
        ++i;
    }
    else {
        ...
        i = mappedA.erase(i);
    }
}
```

Further aside, you might consider using c++ *structured bindings* to make the code more readable and do fewer of the same lookups.  Putting that all together:

```
for (auto iterA = begin(mapcheckA), endA = end(mapcheckA); iterA != endA; ) {
    auto& [keyA, valueA] = *iterA;
    if (auto iterB = mapcheckB.find(keyA); iterB != end(mapcheckB)) {
        auto& [keyB, valueB] = *iterB;
        if (valueA >= valueB) {
          valueA -= valueB;
          mapcheckB.erase(iterB);
          ++iterA;
        } else {
          valueB -= valueA;
          iterA = mapcheckA.erase(iterA);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: both halves of the *if* update the iterA rather than doing it in the for-loop, since one uses ++ and the other takes the result of calling erase.